# Updates don't finish installing on Windows 7 Professional 32-bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

I have a problem when applying updates on my Windows 7 system.

On Windows Update it shows the *Installing updates* status - but it never completes.

[image: Screenshot]

What could be the problem? How can I get the updates to finish installing as would be normal?

Comment: do you have enough hard disk space on your disk C: ?

Comment: certainly, about 100 Mb

Comment: 100 Mb may be not enough for such updates as SP1 which requires 700 Mb

Comment: oh... sorry... 100 Gb.. :)

Comment: De-select the Net framework 4 update from the list, see if they will install now.

Answer (score 0):

G-71,

Just some thoughts:

If you have enough disk space, one possible cause is that the Windows updates you are trying to install might be waiting for a required file to be unlocked or worse, a previous update may have corrupted some files and it is preventing the current updates from installing.  The fast way to resolve this issue would be to reinstall windows. That's my own personal preference in these situations, because it will also help you more quickly identiy an underlying physical fault with the hard drive as well if it occurs again.

The slow but "you may get lucky" approach would be to click on 'installed updates' in the bottom left of the screen above and start removing installed updates up until the point you are certain that the problem wasn't occurring and then try to reinstall them again (if re-installing windows is something you really want to avoid). However, this may not work and you will have to turn around and do option 1 anyway.